# Converting negative BigInteger (Tom Wu's JSBN library) values to hex values

Tags: javascript, biginteger, jsbn

I am trying to convert BigInteger numbers to its hex format so that I could use it for further HMAC calculations.
I have used the following post for getting the code to do this.

[Converting a 64 bit number string to word array using CryptoJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841942/converting-a-64-bit-number-string-to-word-array-using-cryptojs)

The code works perfectly fine for positive BigInteger Numbers but doesn't produce the correct results when used for negative BigInteger Numbers.

For example: Consider the code piece below from the linked post:

```
function intToWords(num, lengthInBytes) {
    var bigInt = new BigInteger();
    bigInt.fromString(num, 10); // radix is 10
    var hexNum = bigInt.toString(16); // radix is 16

    if (lengthInBytes && lengthInBytes * 2 >= hexNum.length) {
        hexNum = Array(lengthInBytes * 2 - hexNum.length + 1).join("0") + hexNum;
    }

    return CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexNum);
}
```

I passed the **num** value as **-52** and **lengthInBytes** value as **8**. 
The **hexNum**(third line of the intToWords function) generated is **"-34"** (instead of being **"ffffffffffffffcc"**)

Could someone help me to correctly convert the input number to its right Hex format?

Comment: @artjomb I have added you to this post as you helped on the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. The library was returning the right hex value. I just had to get the 2's compliment of the hex number(line 3).